# Alignment to the decimal point for negative numbers

Tags: alignment

I tried to align the numbers in the table to the decimal point. This has also worked so far.
However, with negative numbers, the alignment no longer works. The numbers are shifted too far to the left.
Unfortunately, I can not find the error.

Can someone help me?

Many thanks in advance!

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{table-format=2.1, table-space-text-post={***}} 
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\makegapedcells 
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} 
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{$}r<{$}@{\,}>{$}l<{$} | S | *{4}{S} @{}}
\Xhline{1.2pt}
\mcc{2}[c|]{\makecell[t]{CAAR\\Window}} 
    & \mcc{1}[c|]{\makecell[t]{All\\transaction\\forms}} 
        & \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of\\ Partial Interest}} 
            & \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of\\ Majority Assets}} 
                &  \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Acquisition Of \\ Remaining Interest}} 
                    & \mcc{1}{\makecell[t]{Merger}}\\
\Xhline{0.8pt}
(-15,   & -2)   &  1.7*** & 1.3**  &  1.8**  &  2.2*** &  2.0***    \\
(-10,   & -1)   &  1.9*** & 0.9**  &  2.2*** &  2.4*** &  2.5***    \\
 (-5,   & -1)   &  1.3*** & 0.9*** &  1.2*** &  1.4*** &  1.7***    \\
 (-5,   & +5)   & 13.3*** & 5.7*** & 12.2*** & 14.7*** & 20.9***    \\
 (-2,   & +2)   & 12.6*** & 5.5*** & 11.1*** & 13.8*** & 19.9***    \\
 (-1,   & +1)   & 11.8*** & 5.0*** &  9.8*** & 11.9*** & 19.4***    \\
  (0,   & 0)    &  8.7*** & 3.0*** &  6.3*** &  7.0*** & 16.0***    \\
  (0,   & +10)  & 12.1*** & 4.9*** & 10.7*** & 13.5*** & 19.4***    \\
  (1,   & +10)  &  3.4*** & 1.8*** &  4.4*** &  6.5*** &  3.5***    \\
  (2,   & +15)  &  1.2*** & -0.4   &  1.6**  &  2.1*** & -1.4***    \\
\Xhline{1.2pt}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: If you have a sign you probably want to include it in the table specification: `table-format=-2.1` (untested because the code shown so far is not a compilable document and I couldn't figure out all the packages needed to make the code compile just now).

Comment: Yes ist works. Thank You!